# How to throw out my local changes and clone one branch from repository

Tags: git, pycharm

I accidentally make few commits in branch "develop" instead of my 'task'-branch. Now, when I create new branch from develop, I always have these previous commits. So, I need to pull ALL develop branch from repository and need to discard all my local changes and commits.
How can I do this without full clone repository to a new folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# on your develop branch
$ git checkout develop

# create the branch you want that should have the commits in develop
$ git branch task

# force the develop branch back to its original state
$ git reset --hard origin/develop

# switch to your task branch, and continue committing
$ git checkout task
```